# GPG. Encrypting with RSA key instead of public key

Tags: encryption, key, gnupg

I have a public key(`my_frnd_public_key.key`) which I imported using the following command:

```
gpg --import /new_folder/my_frnd_public_key.key
gpg --list-keys
/users/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
----------------------------------
pub   4096R/6586351E 2014-11-20
uid                  nikhil
sub   4096R/30CFV11Z 2014-11-20

pub   1024R/X193456 2006-02-09
uid                  user1
```

When I'm encrypting a file using that key through a script, it gets encrypted with my ssh RSA key instead of `user1` key.

When i do this on command line:

```
gpg --encrypt --trust-model always -r "user1" output.txt
```

It picks up the right key.

I'm new to this GPG.
Can you please let me know what might be the problem?

EDIT -- added information:

The script used that doesn't work, we are using it to call from informatica.

```
#!/bin/sh
RECIPIENT=$1
OUTPUT=$2
gpg --encrypt --trust-model always -r "$RECIPIENT" $OUTPUT
```

I call it with `sh /usr/scripts/encrypt_file.sh 'user1' t_users.txt`

Comment: Could you show us your script?

Comment: #!/bin/sh

RECIPIENT=$1
OUTPUT=$2

gpg --encrypt --trust-model always -r "$RECIPIENT" $OUTPUT




a simple script. we are using this script to call it from informatica.

Comment: Could you put the script and the way it is called inside your question ?

Comment: sh /usr/scripts/encrypt_file.sh 'user1' t_users.txt

Comment: Do you get the same result if you specify the key id as the recipient, rather than the uid? eg `sh /usr/scripts/encrypt_file.sh 'X193456' t_users.txt`

Comment: As an aside, it's worth adding `keyid-format 0xlong` to your `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` and always referring to keys by their long id. Short ids (32bit) are now easy to spoof (eg generate a new key whose short id collides with someone else's) which can lead to all sorts of trouble :)

Comment: One of the keys that i got has spaces in its name, thats the reason why i had that issue.